# Laravel Social Auth

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, oauth

Для аутентификации использую пакет OAuth Service Provider for Laravel 5.
Ссылка: [пакет на GitHub](https://github.com/oriceon/oauth-5-laravel)

Мне нужно получить Имя, идентификатор, email и фото пользователя.
Задаю в настройках: 

`'consumers' => [
        'Facebook' => [
            'client_id'     => '154296678252148',
            'client_secret' => '510f35aaee96bce81552ba66e678a2d0',
            'scope'         => ['email', 'public_profile'],
        ],];`

Ожидаю получить имя, код и email. Но получаю только имя и код.

`array:2 [▼
  "name" => "Valentine Murnik"
  "id" => "861228687278984"
]`

Почему не удается получить email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения почты надо запросить user:email

```
user:email  Grants read access to a user’s email addresses.
```

Список прав гитхаба
https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes